# django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I am overwriting an inline template - in  my template I used:

```
{% for line in fieldset %}
  {% for field in line %}
    <td class="original {{ field.field.name }}">
    <div name="foobar_a">
    {% ifequal field.field.name "rule_type" %}
        {% ifequal field.field "2" %}
          fine
        {% endifequal %}
    {% endifequal %}
    </div>
```

{{ field.field }}
        
              
            {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}

```
    </tr>

 {% endfor %}
```

But this doesn't work because the `field.field` gives a HTML tag and the value of the field, i.e:

```
<input id="id_waprule_set-0-rule_type" type="hidden" value="2" name="waprule_set-0-rule_type"/>
2
```

Because of this my `ifequal` is not working.

Is there any way that I can get the only value i.e '2' without using JavaScript?

Comment: Please don't use a mixture of tabs and spaces in your code, it makes it very, very hard to read. Also, I hope you close those `{% for %}` tags!

Comment: field.field.name is working correct i have checked it.the inner if is not working.

Comment: what a horrible code to read, can you consider reading yourself before posting?

Answer (score 1):

Try `field.field.value` (if `field.field.name` is working, this should too).